# Finding critical points of a function.

Tags: calculus

The question reads y=x-4x/(x+1)

It also asks what the critical points are and the min and max values.

I know that I need to figure out the derivative and then set that equal to zero to find the critical points. However, how do I solve the min and the max?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maxima and minima are critical points too. At maxima and minima, the first derivatives will be zero also. In their case, you have to check the second derivative at that point. If the second derivative is positive, it is a minima and if negative, then it is a maxima. And if it is zero, then it is a stationary point and then you have to go further checking higher order derivatives. As for your function, checking the second derivative will be enough.